# How to match several E-mail addresses using regular expression in linux?

Tags: linux, regular-expression

```
Tom.riddle@island.ac.kr
Ron_Weasley@island.ac.kr
harry2020@island.ac.kr
```

How to match these email addresses ? Any email address ending with island.ac.kr

Comment: A regular expression that matches them is `.*@island.ac.kr` or `.*island.ac.kr`. Which tool are you going to use to match them?

Comment: @berndbausch Those would also match `name@islandpac.kr.com` though.

Comment: @Kusalananda oh no. You are right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
.*@island\.ac\.kr$
```

Example:

```
$ cat /tmp/111
Tom.riddle@island.ac.kr
Ron_Weasley@island.ac.kr
harry2020@island.ac.kr
itai@gmail.com
what.ever@island.ac.kr
abc@what.ac.kr
```

```
$ grep '.*@island\.ac\.kr$' /tmp/111
Tom.riddle@island.ac.kr
Ron_Weasley@island.ac.kr
harry2020@island.ac.kr
what.ever@island.ac.kr
```

The dots after the `@` sign need to be escaped.

Comment: wow thank u so much!!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: well /tmp/111 <- what does this mean btw? i couldnt clearly get it :/

Comment: This is a temporary file where I've placed the examples you provided in your question.

Comment: If these are email addresses make sure you use a case-insensitive match, as the domain part isn't required (by specification) to be lowercase

Comment: then if i list up all the email addresses(random@island.ac.kr) in linux, i should commend like this ->  "$ grep *@island\.ac\.kr $" am i right?

Comment: @mimiko, put the regex inside single ticks like this: 'regex' .

Comment: $ grep [a-zA-z0-9]@island\.ac\.kr$ <- is it right?

Comment: @ this "at" need to be escaped, then $ grep [a-zA-z0-9]\@island\.ac\.kr $ <- is it right? wow its so confusing

Comment: @mimiko Why not just use the regular expression that was mentioned in the answer?

Comment: $ grep *@island\.ac\.kr $   and $ grep [a-zA-z0-9]@island\.ac\.kr$ these both mean exactly the same then?

Comment: my prof want me to do that :(

Comment: You should single-quote the expression, and your own suggestion doesn't match all valid emails. If that's what your Professor is telling you to do then they are wrong unless you can guarantee the format of the username parts of emails for this domain

Comment: @mimiko They are not the same, and both are defective. If that's what your professor says to use, ask him to visit this site some time. He might learn something.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and assuming that the input consists of one email address per line.

```bsh
awk -F @ 'tolower($NF) == "island.ac.kr"' input.txt
```

or, if you want lower-case output always,

```bsh
awk -F @ 'tolower($NF) == "island.ac.kr" { print tolower($0) }' input.txt
```

This treats each line as a set of `@`-delimited fields.  When the last field (`$NF`), turned into all lower-case, is exactly `island.ac.kr`, the line is printed.

Testing:

```
$ cat input.txt
Tom.riddle@island.ac.kr
Ron_Weasley@island.ac.kr
harry2020@island.ac.kr
itai@gmail.com
what.ever@island.ac.kr
abc@what.ac.kr
example@island.ac.kr.com
```

```
$ awk -F @ 'tolower($NF) == "island.ac.kr"' input.txt
Tom.riddle@island.ac.kr
Ron_Weasley@island.ac.kr
harry2020@island.ac.kr
what.ever@island.ac.kr
```

If you want to also match addresses like `name@something.island.ac.kr`, you could use `awk` like so:

```bsh
awk -F @ 'tolower($NF) ~ /island\.ac\.kr$/'
```

Or, with `grep` and `tr`,

```bsh
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <input.txt | grep 'island\.ac\.kr$'
```

where `tr` is used to fold all characters into lower-case, and `grep` is then used to pick out the relevant lines.

Or just

```bsh
grep -i 'island\.ac\.kr$' input.txt
```

if you don't mind possibly getting mixed case output.